# Admob code not working

Tags: android, admob

The following code is what I implemented just to check admob ads retrieval but I couldn't get any ads although the code is even no crashing.
Please inform what is wrong in this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public AdView  admobView;
    public View mainView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        admobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "Top secret");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        admobView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //mainView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        //tested this
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator

        //tested this
        //adRequest.addTestDevice("20cb18e8ffc74ad2");

        //tested this
        //adRequest.addMediationExtra("3d879f364d5747c5", null);
        admobView.loadAd(adRequest);
        layout.addView(admobView);
        //layout.addView(mainView);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an `onReceiveAd()` or an `onFailedToReceiveAd()` notice in LogCat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add permissions and congifchanges of admob in your menifest. Cause i have run your code and it displayed in my emulator. And also in order to display add your app's targetSdkVersion need to be greater then 14.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
```

Activity is as like you

```
public AdView  admobView;
    public View mainView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        admobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14f39f0b52dce6");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        admobView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //mainView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        //tested this
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator

        //tested this
        //adRequest.addTestDevice("20cb18e8ffc74ad2");

        //tested this
        //adRequest.addMediationExtra("3d879f364d5747c5", null);
        admobView.loadAd(adRequest);
        layout.addView(admobView);
        //layout.addView(mainView);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

And Manifest is ==

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ee"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how can i call it above if the "layout" variable is declared downwards?

Comment: The code above is not crashing actually, i can't this thing in the logcat but ads are not visible.

I/Ads(601): Received ad url: <url: "http://e.admob.com:80/mads/mediate?preqs=0&session_id=13498120987146917996&u_sd=0.75&seq_num=1&slotname=20cb18e8ffc74ad2&u_w=320&msid=com.example.checkingapp&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-............